# Problem while parsing node with html tags

Tags: android

Friend's
   I'm parsing an xml file from web service,it contains html tags,when i use the particular node like description ,the parser simply escapes to parse.for example below content 
i use to parse it simply skipped from parsing

```
**<desc>
<![CDATA[<img src=http://www.browndailyherald.com/polopoly_fs/1.2403115!image/2344905136.jpg_gen/thumbnails/100x100/2344905136.jpg><br /><br><p>
    Coal to men at Brown, only 11 percent of whom told us they are gay. Our bitter heterosexual female staffers tell us that number must be higher.
...</p>]]>
</desc>**
```

How can i resolve this issue.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract contents of CDATA and parse it with HTML parser.

Comment: That depends on what XML parser you use. Your parser should provide you with a way to retrieve CDATA blocks; please check documentation.